# Redirect rule to allow sub.domain.com to only serve images

Tags: redirect

I need help with a redirect rule.

I created a subdomain `sub.abc.com` and set it's public_html to that of `abc.com`.

This means public_html is now accessible either by `abc.com` or by `sub.abc.com` .

I want to limit this so that `sub.abc.com` only provides access to images in `wp-content/uploads` any other requests to `sub.abc.com` should be redirected to `abc.com/url/url` .

Here is what i have tried creating

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

so if the user is accessing `cdn.example.com/wp-content/uploads/1/1/file.jpg`  then there is no redirect, but if they are trying to access `cdn.example.com/post/post` or  `cdn.example.com/anything-else`  then it will redirect to `example.com/post/post` or `example.com/anything-else` .

Comment: Are you using `Apache` server?

Comment: using litespeed.

Comment: Anwar Are you using `htaccess` or `server.config` for the rules?

Answer (score 0):

The following rule should work for you. Remember to put it at the of your `htaccess` or `server.config` file before others rules otherwise these rules may override it.

```
RewriteEngine on

#serve only images  on abc.example.com
#redirect to main domain if request is not for images
######################
#if the host is "sub.example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
#and the request is not for images and /wp-content/uploads
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/wp-content/uploads/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$ [NC]
#redirect the request to main domain
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

This will redirect your `sub.example.com` with request string to `example.com` if the subdomain is used for requests  other then `images` .
Replace `sub.example.com` and `example.com` with your real domain name in the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`  above.
If this works and you are happy with the redirect then change `R=302` to `R=301` to make the redirection permanent.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225710/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-verma-redirect-rule-to-allow-sub-domain-com-to-only).